# How to create a custom processor for audio files in Ruby on Rails(5) with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, paperclip

So I'm trying to convert mp3 files into .flac with Paperclip custom processors and ffmpeg. The following code runs the ffmpeg command and creates a temporary flac file. However, it is not saved? Currently only the original file is saved. What am I missing here?

```
class AudioFile < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :raw_audio, processors: [:custom], styles: { original: {}}
```

the custom processor

```
module Paperclip
 class Custom < Processor

  def initialize(file, options = {}, attachment = nil)
    super
    @file = file
    @basename = File.basename(@file.path)
    @format = options[:format] || 'flac'
    @params = options[:params] || '-y -i' 
  end

  def make
    source = @file
    output = Tempfile.new([@basename, ".#{@format}"])
    begin
      parameters = [@params, ':source',':dest'].join(' ')
      Paperclip.run('ffmpeg', parameters, :source => File.expand_path(source.path), :dest => File.expand_path(output.path), :sample_rate => @sample_rate, :bit_rate => @bit_rate)
    end
   output
  end

 end
end
```

Comment: `mp3 into .flac`  - attemptoing to go from lossy to lossless = impossible. Nope. This would be like taking an image that is 100 x 100 pixels and resizing it to 1000 x 1000.

Comment: it's more about the extension than the quality of the audio. I'm using the google speech api which only accepts flac or raw audio

Comment: Do you have `log_command: true` in your Paperclip config? Even if not, check your logs for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into exactly the same problem.

You can use ffmpeg directly (note the backticks)

```
`ffmpeg -i <original_file_path.mp3> <new_file_path.flac>`
```

There are various other things you can do (and need to in the case of Google Speech API).

e.g. If you have an mp3 file in stereo, you're going to need to either

compress to mono:

```
`ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -ac 1 file_mono.flac`
```

or split the channels:

```
`ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -map_channel 0.0.0 left_file.flac -map_channel 0.0.1 right_file.flac`
```

otherwise the API won't accept it.